# Could someone please me figure out what I am doing wrong in jQuery in order to get this "Can't find Variable: $" code whenI try and open my modal?

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

```js
 

$(function(){
        var $modal = $('#ModalContact');
        var $open = $('#jsOpenContact');
        var $close = $('.CloseX');
        var $win = $("window");

        $open.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $modal.show();
        });

        $close.on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $modal.addClass('.out')
        });

        $win.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $modal.addClass('.out')
        });

    });
```

```css
    .NavContact a {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #ModalContent {
        background-color: darkred;
        margin: 25% auto;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 75%;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .Contact {
        display: none;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        transform:scaleY(.01) scaleX(0);
        animation:unfoldIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
    }
    .open {
        transform:scaleY(.01) scaleX(0);
        animation:unfoldIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
    }
    #ModalBackground {
        transform:scale(0);
        animation: zoomIn .5s .8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
    }

    @keyframes unfoldIn {
        0% {transform:scaleY(.005) scaleX(0);}
        50% {transform:scaleY(.005) scaleX(1);}
        100% {transform:scaleY(1) scaleX(1);}
    }
    @keyframes zoomIn {
        0% {transform:scale(0);}
        100% {transform:scale(1);}
    }


    .out {
        transform:scale(1);
        animation:unfoldOut 1s .3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
    }
    #ModalBackground .out {
        animation: zoomOut .5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
    }
    @keyframes unfoldOut {
        0% {transform:scaleY(1) scaleX(1);}
        50% {transform:scaleY(.005) scaleX(1);}
        100% {transform:scaleY(.005) scaleX(0);}
    }
    @keyframes zoomOut {
        0% {transform:scale(1);}
        100% {transform:scale(0);}
    }

    .CloseX {
        color: black;
        float: right;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .CloseX:hover {
        color: green;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="NavContact"><a href="#" id="jsOpenContact"> Contact </a></div>
      </nav>

       <div id="ModalContact" class="Contact" >
        <div id="ModalBackground">
        <div id="ModalContent">
         <span class="CloseX">  &times; </span>
         <h4 class="ModalHeader"> Contact Me </h4>
         <p class="contact"> Email <br>  <a href="mailto:sumayyahameerah@yahoo.com"> sumayyahameerah@yahoo.com </a> </p>
         <p class="contact"> Instagram <br>  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sumayyah.ameerah/" target="_blank">  sumayyah.ameerah </a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
         
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Users/sumayyahameerah/Downloads/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Users/sumayyahameerah/Downloads/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script> **
```

I got my modal to work using Javascript yet, I wanted the function using jQuery instead. I really don't understand where I am incorrect here. Do I not have the correct scripts? I'm not sure why my modal won't open on the on click. HELP. every time I go to the console to check it says "Can't find variable: $" I have used all of those scripts that are there to try and figure it out.

Comment: Where exactly is that first block of code?  Is it somewhere inside the HTML block?

The order matters.  You are pulling in 5 copies of jquery -- ensure you are pulling in just one copy, and not from your hard drive :-) .  And make sure the code block that begins with `$(function(){...` is AFTER that.

Comment: The first block of code is what I'm using in jQuery to make my modal work on the click function.

Comment: Yes, I realize.  I asked **where** it is in relation to the HTML you posted.  If it's before the `script` tags that pull in `jquery`.shown in your last block of HTML, that would explain it.  You must include `jquery` once, and **then** start using `$`.  `jquery` makes `$` available.

Comment: The first block of code isn't in the HTML at all, it is in a separate .js file that I linked to my HTML. The scripts for jQuery are before my body tags on the HTML. Also, I have switched to using only one form of jQuery and still, it is not working and sending me the message that the variable cant be found.

Comment: The error you are getting is because the script that you have used is not compatible with your browser. I can see that you have used three js scripts for Jquery. This is a mess. Just include min.js script link and min.css file to have a cleaner code. Check after that.

Comment: Thanks you both for your assistance. @user2740650

Answer (score 0):

First of you dont need to include so many jquery references. Second you don't need to use the `.` in `$modal.addClass('.out')` it has to be `$modal.addClass('out')`

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  var $modal = $('#ModalContact');
  var $open = $('#jsOpenContact');
  var $close = $('.CloseX');
  var $win = $("window");

  $open.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $modal.show();
  });

  $close.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $modal.addClass('out')
  });

  $win.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $modal.addClass('out')
  });

});
```

```css
.NavContact a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

#ModalContent {
  background-color: darkred;
  margin: 25% auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 75%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.Contact {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: scaleY(.01) scaleX(0);
  animation: unfoldIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
}

.open {
  transform: scaleY(.01) scaleX(0);
  animation: unfoldIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
}

#ModalBackground {
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: zoomIn .5s .8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
}

@keyframes unfoldIn {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(.005) scaleX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(.005) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.out {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: unfoldOut 1s .3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
}

#ModalBackground .out {
  animation: zoomOut .5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) forwards;
}

@keyframes unfoldOut {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(.005) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(.005) scaleX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

.CloseX {
  color: black;
  float: right;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.CloseX:hover {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="NavContact"><a href="#" id="jsOpenContact"> Contact </a></div>


<div id="ModalContact" class="Contact">
  <div id="ModalBackground">
    <div id="ModalContent">
      <span class="CloseX">  &times; </span>
      <h4 class="ModalHeader"> Contact Me </h4>
      <p class="contact"> Email <br> <a href="mailto:sumayyahameerah@yahoo.com"> sumayyahameerah@yahoo.com </a> </p>
      <p class="contact"> Instagram <br> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sumayyah.ameerah/" target="_blank">  sumayyah.ameerah </a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```